# It would abort when start cobalt with no ip address

Tags: cobalt

It would abort when start cobalt with no ip address(platform does not have a ip address), can cobalt just send msg to SbSystemRaisePlatformError when it can not reach the url(eg, no ip; has network, but can not visit youtube.com)?

```
[cobalt]>SIGABRT signal
[cobalt]>
[cobalt]>Caught signal: SIGABRT (6)
[cobalt]>       <unknown> [0xb60076d0]
[cobalt]>       <unknown> [0xb60064d8]
[cobalt]>       <unknown> [0xb60078a4]
[cobalt]>       SbSystemGetErrorString [0x11b434]
[cobalt]>       JSONStringValueSerializer::~JSONStringValueSerializer() [0x1069e4]
[cobalt]>       logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0xc40f8]
[cobalt]>       logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0xc40f8]
[cobalt]>       logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0xc40f8]
[cobalt]>       logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0xc40f8]
[cobalt]>       logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0xc40f8]
[cobalt]>       logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0xc40f8]
[cobalt]>       logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0xc40f8]
[cobalt]>       logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage() [0xc40f8]
```

Comment: This just sounds like a bug. Please file an issue at Cobalt's issue tracker.

Comment: OK, I will key a issue to the Cobalt's issue tracker. Thank you!

Comment: The issue url is :  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64548727